# Find infinite loop in delphi 6

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints, delphi-6

The program I currently have has multiple components compiled as dll's. In one of these dll's the program forms an infinite loop. Is there someway to see where the program loops? Even where it is running currently. I don't have a problem doing this check in each dll separately, I have limited the bug to only one of 6.

I am using Delphi 6 on Windows 7.

So in short I want some means to tell me where the program is currently in. Normally you insert a breakpoint and wait for the program to reach that position. But I have no idea where the loop is or in which component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you know the program is in a loop while running under the debugger, just 'pause' it. Looking at the call stack you'll be able to figure out what it is doing. You can find 'pause' in the IDE toolbar or in the 'Run' menu as 'Program Pause'.